# How to read files on the back end of a browser application?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, file, backend

I'm a beginner so I'm sure this is a pretty basic question.

I built a JavaScript application that worked by looking up information in a large .csv file based on user input - I got this working using node.js's file system. Now I've inserted the code into an HTML doc and can't figure out how to achieve the same effect. All the things I find on Google allow the page to read files uploaded by the user - but I have one specific file that I always want to be readable to the back end of my script.

How do you import files into an HTML doc? I haven't had any luck with 'import' or 'require' keywords.

Comment: You just need [AJAX and a csv parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+ajax+csv+file+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: Node is your backend; when you put JS code in an HTML document, it's frontend (because it'll get sent to the browser and runs on the user's machine, inside the browser). The only way for frontend code to read a file is to use an `<input type="file">` and let the user select the file from their hard drive. Not what you're looking for I guess. I don't understand why you're trying to insert perfectly fine server-side code into your HTML document in the first place?

Comment: That's not possible, unless you use a wrapper like https://www.electronjs.org/. Your browser's JavaScript runtime has no direct access to your file system and a lot of other things that you'd expect from NodeJS. Also I am not sure what you mean by "back end of your script". I think there is a misconception on your side. What you can do is actually serve the needed file by a back end and get that into your "HTML script" by a XMLHttpRequest or one of the countless wrappers like axios.

Comment: Hi - I think you're right about me not completely understanding front end vs. back end, etc. I'll try and simplify the problem: how do I allow my client-side code to reference a file (not a file that the user inputs, but a specific .csv file that my JS needs to reference)?